# import javax.persistence couldn't be resolved in my first Maven Hibernate Project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, annotations

I am trying to create my first Maven Project after reading books and articles for a month now :) But the start is not that smooth one like I expected. I have been fiddling with my POM.xml with various dependency artifacts to enable hibernate annotation but nothing seems to be working. I am always getting error that javax.persistence.Entity or any other annotation is not resolved in import.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>FirstHibernateExample</groupId>
      <artifactId>FirstHibernateExample</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>FirstHibernateExample</name>
      <description>This is my first project with Hibernate</description>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
       <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>JBoss repository</id>
          <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.Net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <dependencies>
    <!-- Javaee API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.31</version>
</dependency> 
<!-- Hibernate core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate annotation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anybody point me out where I am wrong or what should I do to get my first project running ? Very thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have downloaded a existing  sample maven hibernate project from mkyong.com and even that project has the same issue in my eclipse. Should I include my maven repository in classpath ? or something else ?

Comment: try this http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/maven-spring-mvc-hibernate-sitemesh-hello-world-project.html

Comment: thanks ekansh :) I will check that too once I get time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the below command fixed the issue.
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSource=true

I found it from below link
http://w3facility.org/question/javax-persistence-sources-where/

Hopefully it will help someone in future :)

EDIT : In another project I just right clicked the error import statement and clicked on fix project setup. It suggested me to add buildpath to javaee-api6.0.jar in M2_REPO which fixed the issue.